# SQL statement with GeoJSON driver in GDAL 2.2 not working

Tags: gdal, geojson

In GDAL 2.1.2 I was able to query from a GeoJSON data source using the following:

```
ogr2ogr -f geojson -dialect sqlite -sql "select * from OGRGeoJSON where NAME in ('Albania','Algeria')" countries.json world.json
```

Whereas in GDAL 2.2.4 this results in the following error:

```
ERROR 1: In ExecuteSQL(): sqlite3_prepare_v2(select * from OGRGeoJSON where NAME in ('Albania','Algeria')):
  no such table: OGRGeoJSON
```

What's changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [GeoJSON documentation for GDAL 2.2](http://www.gdal.org/drv_geojson.html):

> Starting with GDAL 2.2, the layer name is built with the following logic:
>
> If a "name" member is found at the FeatureCollection level, it is used.
>   Otherwise if the filename is regular (ie not a URL with query parameters), then the filename without extension and path is used as the layer name.
>   Otherwise OGRGeoJSON is used.

From this it seems the new syntax should be:

```
ogr2ogr -f geojson -dialect sqlite -sql "select * from world where NAME in ('Albania','Algeria')" countries.json world.json
```

Comment: And there is no need to guess the name of the layer because you can check if with `ogrinfo world.json`.