# Merge ("dissolve") OSM LineStrings from GeoJSON with ST_UNION

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, geojson, ogr2ogr

I would like to merge the continuous LineStrings from a GeoJSON export of an OpenStreetMap relation ([get](https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/yDF) from Overpass Turbo):

```
  "geometry": {
    "type": "LineString",
    "coordinates": [
```

In another question I'm told to use:

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -explodecollections output.geojson input.geojson
-dialect sqlite -sql "SELECT LineString, ST_Union(geometry) as geometry FROM OGRGeoJSON GROUP BY LineString"
```

but since GDAL 2.2 "OGRGeoJSON" is [no longer working](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/282119/sql-statement-with-geojson-driver-in-gdal-2-2-not-working).

How can I now dissolve such features?

Comment: Have you tried the solution from the post you have mentioned?

Comment: Yes, sorry for not linking it. I'm getting "no such column: LineString" because I don't know what to select!

Comment: you can't refer to the *type*, only *properties* nodes are parsed as column references. also, grouping by each feature would, well, be the exact opposite of dissolving...if you want to merge them all, just use `ST_Union(geometry)`, if there are properties, group either accordingly, aggregate or dismis them. btw., shouldn't you also use `... FROM input`?